# Static Website Hosting on Object Storage in Open Telekom Cloud

Tags: object-storage

I have my frontend application hosted on Object Storage in Open Telekom Cloud as a Static website. By default, after setting up the static website I got endpoint in the format https://bucket-name.obs-website.eu-de.otc.t-systems.com. (SSL Certificate is generated by Open Telekom Cloud and it is *.t-systems.com)
This is okay when I use the default endpoint, but when I want to use custom domain name and I want to add TLS/SSL certificate I am not able to use HTTPS protocol, because the service doesn't support it. That was mentioned in the documentation. Is there a way how to bypass this and to be able to use custom domain names? I must use Open Telekom Cloud or if there is any alternative service it needs to be in EU.

I have tried to add as a CNAME, but it redirects me to HTTP. I am not sure will Nginx or some other proxy help in this situation or to use some CDN service where I will be able to manage SSL Certificates.

Please respond if you have any suggestions.

Thank you in advance!